# Не могу понять как найти совпадающие значения в словаре HashMap

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. У меня есть HashMap, в котором находится 10 пар "ключ-значение". Под ключем находятся фамилии людей, под значением - имена. Я хочу найти, совпадают ли имена и совпадают ли фамилии в HashMap. Пытался сделать вот так, но не работает. Помогите, кто может.

```
public static int getCountTheSameFirstName(HashMap<String, String> map, String name) {
    //напишите тут ваш код
    int counter = 1;
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair = iterator.next();
        String value = pair.getValue();
        if (value.equals(name)) {
            counter++;
        } else  {
            counter = 1;
        }

    }

        return counter;
}

public static int getCountTheSameLastName(HashMap<String, String> map, String lastName) {
    //напишите тут ваш код

    int count = 1;
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair1 = iterator.next();
        String key = pair1.getKey();
        if (key.equals(lastName)) {
            count++;
        } else  {
            count = 1;
        }

    }

        return count;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

}

Comment: `но не работает` - а подробнее? `Я хочу найти, совпадают ли имена и совпадают ли фамилии` - что это значит? с чем совпадают? при каких условиях?

Comment: Ну во-первых, я так понял, что в качестве параметра в методы передаются определенные имена и фамилии. Они сравниваются с содержимым HashMap и выводят количество совпадений. Но если в HаshMap не может быть повторяющихся значений, то всегда будет либо 1 на выходе, либо ноль. 
Вот я вроде бы и написал так, чтобы сравнивалось значение переданного параметра с содержимым HashMap. Но у меня валидатор не принимает такое решение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) getCountTheSameLastName всегда вернет Вам 1

так как это структура HashMap

HashMap содержит уникальные ключи и по этим ключам дает доступ к данным.
Там никогда не будет одинаковых значений.

```
    map.put("1","1");
    map.put("1","2");
```

в итоге в HashMap останется только ("1","2");

2) getCountTheSameFirstName - тут ошибка в коде.

Вам не надо менять count постоянно на 1. Иначе, когда алгоритм получает последний key, он видит несовпадение с переданным и перезаписывает count.

итого верно будет так:

```
public static int getCountTheSameFirstName(HashMap<String, String> map, String lastName)
{
    //напишите тут ваш код

    int count = 0;
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pair1 = iterator.next();
        String value = pair1.getValue();
        if (value.equals(lastName))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;

}
```

Comment: Надо обдумать, спасибо Вам за помощь.

Comment: [Вот](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/hashmap.php) почитай, там есть подробно. "При этом все ключи обязательно должны быть уникальны, а значения могут повторяться." И нажми голосвалку, если помогло, а то мне коментарии не дает оставлять.